# How to set some fixed width and height for Xlarge

Tags: android

I want to set the layout fixed width and height for every xlarge screens as 480 X 800 at the centre and remaing screen is black. We can observe this on iPads.

Is there any possible solution for this, and can any one suggest for this?

Comment: I want to set the layout fixed width and height for every xlarge screens as 480 X 800 at the centre and remaing screen is black .We can observe this on ipads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to mimic a feature of iOS that's built into the operating system, and used as compatibility solution for iPhone apps running on an iPad.

Android isn't fragmented with regards to screen sizes as iOS is, as coping with screen dimensions is an integral part of Android's layouting system. Your app will scale up to a larger screen and will be perfectly functional.

If you want to tailor the app to make better use of larger screens, you can use resource qualifiers. Supporting multiple screens is very well explained [in this Android API Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

In short, you can accomplish what you're asking by understanding resource qualifiers, but it's a very bad idea to crop your application as you decribed on larger displays.